# tkinter TclError: can't find package treectrl

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, tcl, tk-toolkit, python-module

Just installed tktreectrl as shown in this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ddpYVA-7wq4 but when i try to run my program i'm getting this error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "E:/Python/Competition/Competition.py", line 36, in <module>
listbox = TkTreectrl.MultiListbox(window)
File "E:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\TkTreectrl\MultiListbox.py",line 50, in __init__
Treectrl.__init__(self, master, showroot=showroot, **kw)
File "E:\Programs\Python\lib\site-packages\TkTreectrl\Treectrl.py", line 489, in __init__
ver = master.tk.call('package', 'require', 'treectrl')
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package treectrl
```

Any ideas on what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be an exhaustive answer, but it can be helpful.

It is probably because your [`tcl/tk`](https://www.tcl.tk) version does not contain a subpackage called `treectrl`, from the following error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: can't find package treectrl
```

The wrapper library you are using `TkTreectrl` for `tkinter` has this statement somewhere:

```
ver = master.tk.call('package', 'require', 'treectrl')
```

which means you are trying to import the package `treectrl` from `tk`, but apparently that package does not exist. My advice is to checkout your version of `tcl/tk` and then check if it includes `treectrl`.

You can check your `tcl` and `tk` version with the following commands (on Python 3):

```
>>> import tkinter
>>> tkinter.TkVersion
8.5
>>> tkinter.TclVersion
8.5
>>>
```

Maybe from the following link you can checkout if `treectrl` package is included in the `Tk` version 8.5: https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/

Similarly, you can do it for your `tcl/tk` version, if different from mine.

My guess is that you need first to install `treectrl` which might be an [extension](http://wiki.tcl.tk/6064) for your `tcl/tk` distribution.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when installing TkTreectrl in LINUX.
This problem happens TCL cannot find the treectrl package.
To fix the problem, you have to find the path that TCL is looking for the treectrl package.
Create a TCL file called test.tcl with the following lines.

```
puts $tcl_pkgPath
puts $auto_path
```

Type the following command at the LINUX prompt to run the code and note the output

```
tclsh test.tcl
```

In my case, the output was

```
/usr/lib64/tcl8.6
```

I discovered that my treectrl2.4.1 directory was in /usr/lib, so from the LINUX prompt, I entered the following commands:

```
cd /usr/lib
cp -R treectrl2.4.1 /usr/lib64/tcl8.6/
```

And that fixed the problem for me.